# Why do we use self.head and not just class var head?

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I have a question regarding my implementation of linked lists in python.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class SLL:
    head = None

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
        else:
            t = self.head
            while t.next is not None:
                t = t.next
            t.next = node
    
    def display_all(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print(None)
        else:
            t = self.head
            while t is not None:
                print(t.data, end = ' ')
                t = t.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = SLL()
    b = SLL()
    a.insert_at_end(2)
    b.insert_at_end(1)
    a.insert_at_end(4)
    b.insert_at_end(3)
    a.insert_at_end(6)
    b.insert_at_end(5)
    a.display_all()
    print()
    b.display_all()
```

The code works fine with output...

```
2 4 6 
1 3 5
```

My question is what's the difference between this and the implementation I see online like:

```
class SLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
        else:
            t = self.head
            while t.next is not None:
                t = t.next
            t.next = node
    
    def display_all(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print(None)
        else:
            t = self.head
            while t is not None:
                print(t.data, end = ' ')
                t = t.next
```

Specifically, what's the difference between my implementation using a class var i.e. `head` vs. the other implementation using it as an instance var inside a constructor?

```
head = None` vs. `self.head = None
```

P.S. Apologies if this question has already been answered, I looked and couldn't find an answer (or even how to look for one).

Comment: The big difference will occur if yoiu ever need to establish two different linked lists.  In your implementation, the head is going to be the same for all lists, whereas when you use sel.f.head, the head node will be independent for each linkedlist implementation.

Comment: @itprorh66, *"if you ever need to establish two different linked lists"*: have you noticed that is exactly what they are doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version defines a class attribute. This means that when an instance *reads* `self.head`, it actually reads that class attribute and not the instance attribute (which does not exist yet). The result is the same: it is `None`.

You can see the difference on an *empty* list, by outputting `a.__dict__` before any node is inserted. Notice the difference: the first version shows an empty dictionary, the other shows a `head` key.

However when the code continues and *assigns* a node instance to `self.head`, an instance attribute is targeted in *both* code versions. This means that the first version starts to behave as the second version as soon as the first node has been inserted. All subsequent references to `self.head` are to the instance attribute, not any more the class attribute.

Try to output `a.__dict__` *after* the first node has been added to the list, and you'll now also see the `head` key when using the *first* implementation.

So in this concrete example the practical difference is tiny. The class variable never changes value: it remains `None`, no matter how many lists you create and how many nodes they have. As soon as an instance gets its first node added to it, it starts to use its own `head` attribute.

Comment: Tried what you suggested got the output like:
`{'foot': <__main__.Node object at 0x000002C376DE8E80>}`
`{'foot': <__main__.Node object at 0x000002C376DE8E20>}`. But could you point if my code has any advantage or disadvantage over what the convention is? Thank you!

Comment: I think my answer has all the ingredients for you to decide what is best. It is a matter of opinion (which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow), but I would prefer the second version, as there really is nothing that should be common to all lists you create with this class, and so there should be no need for a class attribute, only an instance attribute.